# Axioms for modal logics based upon counterfactuals

Tags: logic, modal-logic

Suppose we have a logic for counterfactuals as with David Lewis. I here use ⇛ for the counterfactual conditional.  So suppose we have:

Rules:

(1)  If A and A→B are theorems, then B is a theorem.

(2)  If (B<sub>1</sub>∧...)→C is a theorem, then so is ((A⇛B<sub>1</sub>)∧...)→(A⇛C)

Axioms:

(1) All truth functional tautologies

(2) A⇛A

(3) ((A⇛B)∧(B⇛A))→((A⇛C)↔(B⇛C))

(4) (((A∨B)⇛A)∨((A∨B)⇛B))∨(((A∨B)⇛C)↔((A⇛C)∧(B⇛C))

(5) (A⇛B)→(A→B)

(6) (A∧B)→(A⇛B)

Given Lewis's semantics so that α⇛β holds iff β holds in all closest possible worlds where α holds, we may define the modal operator for necessity

**Definition**

□α:=¬α⇛α.

**Question**

How do I most elegantly get modal logics in the hierarchy up to *S5* on the basis of axiomatic principles for ⇛ while presupposing the Definition.

**Initial example**:

Given the Definition and the instance of axiom (5) that (¬α⇛α)→(¬α→α), we immediately get the *T-axiom*: □α→α.

Comment: Unfortunately, Philosophy SE doesn't render LaTeX. If you could translate that to unicode symbols it'd make for an easier read.

Comment: Why should it be possible to prove K syntactically?  It seems like proving it would depend on S5 semantics.

Comment: @Schiphol Yes, unfortunately Philosophy SE does not offer the option to write in  LaTex. Maybe I will translate this tomorrow. Nevertheless, those that know Latex may just copy my posting into a latex editor and so access  a quite readable version.

Comment: @Greg S To prove a statement - as K - syntactically does not rely upon any particular semantics, but upon the axioms and rules of the system presupposed.

Comment: Those who want to scrutinise some of these matters may access a compiled text here:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/302877/axioms-for-modal-logics-based-upon-counterfactuals

Comment: I used https://arachnoid.com/latex/ to display in Mathjax and used the output for the edit.

Comment: define 'rule' sorry i don't understand. do you mean rule as in ruler?

Answer (score 1):

Based on Joseph Jay Zeman's book *[Modal Logic: The Lewis-Modal Systems](https://archive.org/details/modallogiclewism0000zema)* (see the Lemon-style bases in the Appendix), you can prove S5 from L3, RL, L2 and L6.  Since you've proven L3 (T), and your Rule 2 implies RL (N), that leaves L2 (K), and L6 (5).  Ordinarily, K and 5 are axioms, so it's not obvious that they are provable from the syntax of counterfactuals.  I might use a semantic justification for an axiom for 5 or S5 semantics from which K should follow.

If the axiomatization is complete with respect to S5 necessity semantics, you can prove L6.

L6) ¬(A⇛¬A)→((A⇛¬A)⇛¬(A⇛¬A))

For additional information, see [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/304968) answer